# python - sorting with conditions

Tags: python, sorting

Im have various rows on csv, but i just want to sort those who are higher than 0, since i also have negative numbers, so i tried this, and it doesn't seem to work

```
try :
    ligacsv = csv.reader(open('%s/liga.csv', 'r')%BASE_DIR, delimiter='|')

except IOError, e

try:
    ligacsv = csv.reader(open('C:/www/liga.csv', 'r'), delimiter='|')
except: ligacsv=[]


d = sorted(ligacsv, key=lambda x: (int(x[1])>'0'), reverse=False)

for linha in d:
    for i in linha[0:1]]:
        print '<td align="right">%s</td>' %i
```

im outputing in html

Yes, it's badly written i know, i'm still learning the language. This is just a piece of the code, for you guys get the general idea.

when its sorted i get something like 75 74 50 -30 2 15 etc etc

i want it to be 75 74 50 15 2. Without the numbers inferior to 0.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Mind cleaning up that code? there's a LOT wrong with it... And what's the error with it? "doesn't seem to work" isn't really helpful.

Comment: mrok is right you want filter ... or a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

```
d = sorted([row for row in ligascv if int(row[23])>0],
           key = lambda row: int(row[23]),
           reverse = False)
```

Comment: Thank you unutbu, that worked almost marvelous, except for the fact that although it doesn't give me any number below 0, the results aren't in any order i can perceive. Are you kind enough to make it display from the lowest to the highest or vice-versa?

Comment: @DinarteTeixeira: I've modified my answer (by adding the `key` parameter) to sort according to the integer value in the 24th column.